# Please identify this Italian kettle(?)

Tags: equipment

[image]

<sub>(click to enlarge)</sub>

A few years ago, I got this Christmas present; I have to admit that I've forgotten what it is by now. It came in a box branded 'Chiapella', but that's an [Italian salami producer](https://www.chiapellasalumi.it/it/). Not something you'd associate with this, which is clearly meant to hold some kind of liquid. (It *could* be that the box is from another present and doesn't have anything to do with the 'kettle'.) If I remember correctly, it came with a tin can filled with olive oil.

Here's a close-up of the thing and the instructions on the lid:

[image]

<sub>(click to enlarge)</sub>

Above the tap stands the following:

> #### SANSONE
>
> EUROPA MODEL INXO 18/10
>
> ((2))
>
> MADE IN ITALY 14.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Per [the link](https://lanuovasansone.com/?lang=en) @Max provided in the comments: just a container to dispense olive oil... or any other liquid of your choosing.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. I realize this is a follow-up question, but: what advantages does it provide over using a regular bottle (other than that it looks cool)?

Comment: @Glorfindel the only things I can think of are that it eliminates light, and, depending on your kitchen set up, can be more convenient than dealing with a bottle or can, particularly if you buy in bulk...but, you get bonus points for coolness.

Comment: I'd be careful about using any other liquid, the different gaskets might just be good enough for oil.

Comment: @Max the company's website describes this as "made in conformance with the European law on the manufacture of  containers for liquids."  I would think that about covers any other liquid that might be used in the kitchen.

Comment: It does not break as easy as a damigiana and you don't lift it each time.